# NoRegionError in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I see a lot of localized questions for solving the NoRegionError issue in the context of certain AWS resources. Sure; setting AWS_DEFAULT_REGION will solve it. However, I'm not seeing anywhere where anyone is describing why this is necessary in the first place in contexts that should already be inherently region-aware.

If we're talking about a certain task or service running in ECS in Fargate or EC2, which must already be running for/in a certain region, why can't this region be used by default? Why am I having to hardcode the region into environments?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably a question to the various SDK projects. I don't think anyone here could answer that but there's no obvious reason why it couldn't fall back to reading the `placement/region` from the IMDS if the region isn't specified otherwise and the IMDS is available.

Comment: How specifically are you getting that error? Please provide more details and show some code. All the AWS SDKs I've used have detected the region they were running in, when they run from EC2 or ECS.

Comment: I am having the same situation and I have no idea why the same container has NoRegionError when using ECS in EC2 but not when using ECS in Fargate.

Comment: @MarkB By running a task and not specifically setting a region into the environment...

Comment: The AWS CLI tool, and AWS SDKs will automatically pick up the region when running on ECS Fargate (at least newer versions of those tools will).  That's why I asked for specifics about what you are doing to encounter this error.

Comment: @MarkB But not in EC2?

Comment: Yes in EC2 as well.

Comment: That's the issue. It isn't.